# How to pass "this" to another object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

how to pass "this"  to another function ???

```
function demo1()
    {

        demo2(this);
    }
```

how to get this object of demo1 into demo2 ???

```
function demo2()
{
     //how to get this object of demo1 into demo2 ??? 
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I got this correctly, but maybe you are looking for `demo2.call(this);` instead of `demo2(this);`.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this a number of ways.

**Pass it in**
You're already doing this, sort of.

```
function demo1()
{
    demo2(this);
}

function demo2(demo1)
{
    console.log(demo1);
}
```

**Call it in the current scope**

```
function demo1()
{
    // Executes demo2 in scope of demo1
    demo2.call(this);
}

function demo2()
{
    console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function demo1()
    {

        demo2(this);
    }

function demo2(data)
{
     console.log(data);
}
```

Check out the details on console.

Answer (score -3):

That's quite easy to do. You can use `.call` or `.apply`:

```
demo2.call(this);
```

The first argument you provide will be the context (`this`) used during execution.